# How to correctly implement hotkeys in a WinRT application?

Tags: windows-runtime, implementation, shortcut, hotkeys

I tried using Window's ButtonDown event as well as Grid's ButtonDown (all window elements are inside this grid). However, these events never seem to fire.

Where, logically, should the code for handling button down events (as to implement hotkeys) be in a WinRT application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought someone recently blogged about this, but I can't find the post right now. You can check these articles though: [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868246.aspx), [link](http://www.michielpost.nl/PostDetail_71.aspx).

Basically you would handle `Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown`/`Up`, store the current state of the modifier keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>) and respond to combinations to handle them. Then you should also specify accessibility and help strings like these on your controls:

```
ToolTipService.ToolTip="Shortcut key: Ctrl+P"
AutomationProperties.AcceleratorKey="Control P"
```

Comment: thank you. It works! The way it's done with the CoreWindow is funny though, coming from WPF.